# Program sometimes crashes and other time don't

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, free

I am trying to make a program that generates two matrices of the same number of lines and columns (given by the user. numbers on the matrices are also generated)  and then another matrix that is filled with numbers given by the user.

For example, if I ask for matrices with 3 lines and 3 columns, the program sometimes works fine and sometimes it doesn't. In any of the ways, the program always crashes on the end. I've tried to debug but no clue. Might be the compiler? This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int index, i, j, random, k, l;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("How many colums/lines?\n");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    int(*matrix1)[index]=malloc(sizeof(int[index][index]));
    if(matrix1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    for(i=1; i<=index; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=index; j++)
        {
            random = rand()%10;
            matrix1[i][j]=random;
            printf("%d ", matrix1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("\n\n");


    int(*matrix2)[index]=malloc(sizeof(int[index][index]));
    if(matrix2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    for(k=1; k<=index; k++)
    {
        for(l=1; l<=index; l++)
        {
            random = rand()%10;
            matrix2[k][l]=random;
            printf("%d ", matrix2[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    int(*matrix3)[index]=malloc(sizeof(int[index][index]));

    printf("Input the numbers for the third matrix.\n");
    for(i=1; i<=index; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=index; j++)
        {
            printf("Fill the position %d%d\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix3[i][j]);
        }
    }

    free(matrix1);
    free(matrix2);
    free(matrix3);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Which line exactly did it crash on?

Comment: And are you aware that array indices in C start from 0? So the valid indices are 0 to (num_elements-1). In your code `index` is an invalid array index and using that will cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: it crashes on the free functions. Yes, I am aware. Are you refering of the way I am using these for cicles?

Comment: I don't know what "cicles" is. But `for(i=1; i<=index; i++)`  and `for(j=1; j<=index; j++)` will result in accessing `matrix1[index][index]` which is a buffer overrun. It needs to be `for(i=0; i<index; i++)`  and `for(j=0; j<index; j++)`

Comment: What @kaylum is saying is that you need to fix those indices to be 0-based.  As they are now, they are going to cause a problem.  The fact that the actual crash happened during free, not during the array accesses, does *not* mean that you "got away with it" and that the array accesses were okay.

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting what you are saying. Should I do: for(i=0; i<index; i++) then?

Comment: @SteveSummit  many thanks both of you. Now I understand!

Comment: Should add `#include <time.h>`

Comment: @Gazelle Right.  I think you get this now, but the essential point is that when you access `matrix[i][j]`, you must have 0 ≤ `i` < `index` and 0 ≤ `j` < `index`.  If `i` or `j` is *equal* to `index`, yo are accessing memory you don't own, and flirting with disaster.